# Once you catch a shiny Pokemon does the rate change for the second?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I am using the Masuda method in Sword and Shield to breed some shinies. I am trying to get a shiny Gardevoir and Gallade at the moment so I will need 2 shiny Ralts.

I am wondering if after I get the first shiny Ralts will the second shiny Ralts be easier/faster to catch or will the rate simply reset back to 1 in 682.7/512? For example if I use the first shiny to try to breed for the second will that affect the rate at all? I've had a look on Serebii and Bulbapedia but couldn't find an answer to this specifically.

Comment: Why do you think shiny rates will improve with each additional Pokémon you breed? Do you have a source for that?

Comment: Just two? Nah, you need at least four. There are actually two types of shiny - the regular and the square sparks ones :P And considering that the square sparks version is rarer, you may end up with far more regular ones before getting two "square shiny" versions ^_^'

Comment: Yep know this already, it really makes no difference to me which shiny it is so 2 will be enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, obtaining or hatching a shiny Pokemon does not affect the offsprings.
Breeding a shiny Pokemon used to increase the chances only in Gen 2, because the "shininess" of a Pokemon was related to its IVs (Individual Values). This doesn't work anymore since Gen 3.

According to [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny_Pok%C3%A9mon#Pok.C3.A9mon_Sword_and_Shield), the only thing that affects shiny Pokemon is the number of times that the player has caught or defeated each species of Pokémon, which increases the chance of Pokémon of that species appearing as a Brilliant Pokémon, but this only works in the overworld.

Besides the usual *Shiny Charm* and chain fishing, of course.

Comment: Hmm I had suspected as much. Oh well looks like I'll be hatching 1300+ Ralts after all, ouch!

Comment: @FrontEnd Not necessarily. I was shiny hunting in Sword the other week, and got my shiny after 62 hatches :)

Comment: Or you could be as unlucky as me, I hatched more than 3000 eggs in Pokemon Y and couldn't get, for the sake of Arceus, a single shiny Pokemon.