# Do Rotom Rally or Everstones affect shiny rates?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I understand that egg hatching is based on steps, however when doing a Rotom Rally the hatching is essentially paused until after the rally is complete, at which point multiple eggs hatch almost at the same time.
So my question is: if I am trying to breed a shiny via the Masuda method, does using the Rotom Rally have any impact on hatching a shiny vs just hatching via walking/riding around normally?

I haven't been able to find any evidence online of people hatching via Rotom Rally so it makes me wonder whether I've stumbled across an unknown glitch.

Similarly, I understand an Everstone can pass on the nature from parent to egg, but for the Musada method specifically does it affect the shiny rate if the non-Ditto parent is the one holding the Everstone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

According to [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Masuda_method):

> From Generation IV onward, if the two Pokémon in the Day Care have different languages of origin, **when an Egg is generated**, the game will generate extra personality values in an attempt to find one that results in a Shiny Pokémon for the player.

The shiny status is decided when the egg is generated, not when it's hatched, this means that the method used to hatch the egg does not affect your Pokemon.

The Everstone does not have any effect on the "shininess" of the offspring either.

Comment: I read that article several times top to bottom but somehow missed this detail, thank you. Would you know if the catching shiny rate affects the breeding shiny rate at all, I couldn't find details on this? For example if I see a wild shiny (max raid or overworld), it runs off or is caught, will that affect how likely I can breed a shiny of the same specie after this? I can make a new question on this if necessary.

Comment: As already answered [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/405507/87579), the number of times that the player has caught or defeated each species of Pokémon increases the chance of Pokémon of that species appearing as a Brilliant Pokémon in the overworld. Seeing a shiny Pokemon has no effect to the breeding.